# Kivy Flask Buildozer compile apk

Tags: python

I have simple code for Flask local server:

```
import sys
import io
 
sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
sys.stderr = io.StringIO()
 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask
 
# Flask server definition
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Flask Server!'
 
def run_flask_app():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, threaded=True)
 
class ServerApp(App):
 
    def build(self):
        self.server_state_label = Label(text="Server is not running")
        self.start_server_button = Button(text="Start Server")
        self.start_server_button.bind(on_press=self.start_server)
 
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        layout.add_widget(self.server_state_label)
        layout.add_widget(self.start_server_button)
        return layout
 
    def start_server(self, instance):
        try:
            # Start the Flask server in a thread
            server_thread = Thread(target=run_flask_app)
            server_thread.start()
            self.server_state_label.text = "Server is running"
        except Exception as e:
            self.server_state_label.text = "Error starting the server"
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApp().run()
```

I want to compile it to apk for anodrid. I have Win11, installed Oracle VirtualBox with Ubuntu. I installed Kivy, Cython, Buildozer, Flask, etc.
I tried start main.py on Ubuntu, Windows, Anodroid mobile with Pydroid and it works well.
If I compile to apk and install on mobile phone, I see just loading and then app closes itself.
After Buildozer init I changed requirements to python3,flask,kivy,cython and Permissions=INTERNET.
I tried lot of configurations but always the same result = app closes itself.
If I used only gui in kivy, it works well. Other apps also works well - all without Flask.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Just a query: You tried WSL?